# MVC How do I prevent calling Action Method by it's name while only allowing to call it via routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, .net-4.5

I am using `.NET4.5` and `MVC4`, and using routing quite extensively.

I have default page route on action named `Calculator`:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "default",
    "Wills/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Journey", action = "Calculator", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Requirement came in that Url that has action name `Calculator` (which works as `Index` page) would be impossible to call when using

```
http://hostname.com/controller/Calculator
```

and only should work when calling `http://hostname.com/controller`

**How do I prevent calling actionMethod by it's name while only allowing to call it via routing?**

Comment: Does it need to throw out a 404 on `http://hostname.com/controller/Calculator`?

Comment: @Stefan Yes it would be ideal that it looks like it does not exist, but honestly I will be happy with partial solution.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know of a trivial way to accomplish this. You could use an `ActionFilter` to check the incoming URL string and return a 404 if it meets your conditions. In this routing you're defaulting to the `Calculator` action. You might want to consider to use a more general name so you can make a more general fix that works for other controllers as well but that might require a lot of refactoring. Other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks Stefan I like your idea, attribute solution is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Stefan for suggestion, I did action attribute that throws 404 if action called directly - might be not the most elegant solution, but does what I need.

```
public class PreventDirectCallAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl.Contains(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName))
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

usage like:

```
[PreventDirectCall]
public ActionResult Calculator()
{
// your action code.
}
```